# Ruby and Qt integration on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, qt4

Hi 
I wanted to run make an GUI with Qt in Ruby.
I downloaded qt4-qtruby-2.1.0 from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=181&release_id=12479
But when I run cmake in it's directory I get this error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindRUBY.cmake:85 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find Ruby
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install Ruby?   Did you install any dev libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're missing ruby-dev, [the development part of the ruby package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ruby-dev)?

Comment: It looks stupid but I had to change my require 'qt' to require 'qt4' to make it work :) 
Actually I didn't try to build it after fixing the require directive